# Jasmine: Testing whether a method is called by another method

Tags: function, jasmine

I'm trying to test whether a method is being called by a another method.
For an example, this is the function i want to test.

`const funcA = () => { funcB() }`

How can i test if `funcB()` is called while executing `funcA()` by using Jasmine?

Comment: You can create a spy on `funcB` and call `funcA()` and then check if it has been called

Comment: Check out the [Jasmine Documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html), it's all in there.  :)

Comment: @Icepickle i tried to create a spy on it but it will only shows function not called, although i had confirmed the funcB had been called by testing it manually

Comment: @dmcgrandle i tried both jasmine.createspy and spyon, its not working

Comment: i think i did not describe my case clearlly, i posted another question in this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54068845/jasmine-testing-whether-a-method-is-called-by-another-method-from-another-class
sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for helping