# Jasmine: Testing whether a method is called by another method from another class

Tags: node.js, typescript, jasmine

I have 2 classes as below

```
class B {
  public b() { return 1 }
}

class A {
  b: B = new B()
  public run() { return this.b.b() }
}
```

I tried to use the following test to test did method b() from class B, but the test is not working

```
describe('A spy', () => {
  let a: A
  let b: B

  beforeEach(() => {
    a = new A()
    b = new B()
    spyOn(b, 'b')

    a.run()
  })

  it('tracks that the spy was called', () => {
    expect(b.b).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

Did i misunderstood jasmine's testing concept?
i also tried `jasmine.createSpy', its also not working

P.S. i did tried to test it manually and confirmed that the method b() from class B had been called

Comment: a.run() isn’t a spy.  Did you mean to write ‘expect(b.b).toHaveBeenCalled()’?  You could also set it up differently with something like ‘spyOn(a, ‘run’).and.callThrough()’

Comment: @dmcgrandle sorry for the typo
yes i mean to write expct (b.b).toHaveBeenCalled()
i also used ‘spyOn(a, ‘run’).and.callThrough()', its also not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b` variable isn't used anywhere, it isn't same object as `this.b` inside `a`, so `b.b` isn't called.

It should be:

```
a = new A()
spyOn(a.b, 'b')
a.run()

expect(a.b.b).toHaveBeenCalled()
```